# Slice indices must integer

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, ode, numpy-slicing

I am working on ODE circuit suddenly face this problem . How to solve it ?

[image]

Comment: what should i write instead of it ?

Comment: Use `N//2+1` in place of `N/2+1` both in line 13 and 14

Comment: That was also worked, thank you so much, to share your solution with me.@FBruzzesi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, if your N/2 is not an integer, you get such an error.

I would change to `w[0:int(N/2)+1] = 2`....

This is also available for every place you divide `N/2`.